# How to modify a returned property without affecting the actual property in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to modify a returned property without affecting the actual property in Neo4j? I have tried to use SET Clause, but it modifies the actual property in the database.

Take as an example this query for https://console.neo4j.org/:

```
match (n:Crew)
//change n.name = "my_value"
return n
```

How can I get the output below without changing the actual name property?

```
(0:Crew {name:"my_value"})
(1:Crew {name:"my_value"})
(2:Crew {name:"my_value"})
(3:Crew:Matrix {name:"my_value"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [map projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/maps/#cypher-map-projection) to return a map of all the properties of each node, with some of the properties being overridden, like this:

```
MATCH (n:Crew)
RETURN n {.*, name: 'my_value'}
```

However, this will not generate a visualization, since the returned `n` would not be a node (it would just be a map).

If you want to visualize the result, you should look into using [virtual nodes and relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/virtual/virtual-nodes-rels/#_virtual_nodes_rels_example). You should also use the Neo4j Browser instead of https://console.neo4j.org/, as the latter may not properly visualize virtual nodes and relationships.

Comment: I used https://console.neo4j.org/ as an example. Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don' know if this is the right way to achieve this, but here is how I did it:

```
match (n:Crew) 
return {name: "my_value"} as n
```

Other properties of `n` can be placed inside of this custom object.